# All Dynamic Posts defaults to first Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress

I am currently working on an app to retrieve feeds from a wordpress site and list individual posts in a jquery mobile list format. Below is the JS code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var url = 'http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/feed/';
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: document.location.protocol + '//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/services/feed/load?v=1.0&output=json_xml&num=1000&callback=?&q=' + encodeURIComponent(url),
        dataType: 'json',
        error: function () {
            alert('Unable to load feed, Incorrect path or invalid feed');
        },
        success: function (data) {
            var postlist = data.responseData.feed.entries;
            var html = '<ul data-role="listview" data-filter="true">';
            for (var i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                var entry = postlist[i];
                console.log(entry);
                html += '<li>';
                html += '<a href="#articlepost" onclick="showPost(' + entry.id + ')">';
                html += '<div class="etitle">' + entry.title + '</div>';
                html += '<div class="esnippet">' + entry.contentSnippet + '</div>';
                html += '</a>';
                html += '</li>';
            }
            html += '</ul>';
            $("#devotionlist").append(html);
            $("#devotionlist ul[data-role=listview]").listview();
        }
    });
});

function showPost(id) {
    $('#articlecontent').html("Loading post...");
    $.getJSON('http://howtodeployit.com/category/daily-devotion/?json=get_post&post_id=' + id + '&callback=?', function (data) {
        var html = '';
        html += '<h3>' + data.post.title + '</h3>';
        html += data.post.content;
        $('#articlecontent').html(html);
    });
}
```

When I click on any of the 6 posts displayed, only the contents of the first Post gets displayed instead of the contents of the individual posts.

Comment: Have you verified that the server is returning a a different post?  Have you verified that you're not passing in the same id for every link?

Comment: It looks like the Google API while translating the XML feed to JSON, it does not include the post ID. Was hoping to use the Google 'google.feeds.Feed.MIXED_FORMAT' to get additional XML attribute so I could get the Element <guid> and extract the post ID from it but that didn't work

Comment: I did finally workaround this issue which I had already posted in another Post. I will also post it here for others to see

Answer (score 0):

How did I workaround this?

Step1: From my WordPress Permalink Settings, I selected Custom Structure and added **/%postname%/%post_id%** This means my RSS XML output results for my 'Link' element will be in this format:

```
<myurl>/<postname>/<postID> (http://howtodeployit.com/xxx/111/)
```

Step2: To make it easier for me instead of writing a regex query I used a Split command like this:

```
var postlink = entry.link;
var id = postlink.split(/\//)[4];
```

**(///)[4]** would simply split the URL by the number of slashes and take only that 4th bit which is where my postID is.

I hope this comes in handy for others in my position